# Escape double quotes for JSON in Python

Tags: python, string

How can I replace double quotes with a backslash and double quotes in Python?

```
>>> s = 'my string with "double quotes" blablabla'
>>> s.replace('"', '\\"')
'my string with \\"double quotes\\" blablabla'
>>> s.replace('"', '\\\"')
'my string with \\"double quotes\\" blablabla'
```

I would like to get the following:

```
'my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'my string with \\"double quotes\\" blablabla'
>>> s
'my string with \\"double quotes\\" blablabla'
>>> print s
my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla
>>>
```

When you just ask for 's' it escapes the \ for you, when you print it, you see the string a more 'raw' state.  So now...

```
>>> s = """my string with "double quotes" blablabla"""
'my string with "double quotes" blablabla'
>>> print s.replace('"', '\\"')
my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla
>>>
```

Comment: It's the difference between `repr()` and `str()`. `print s` prints the string, while `s` on the command line does the same thing as `print repr(s)`.

Comment: -1 because @zeekay, below, offers a more ideomatic answer: `json.dumps(s)`. It uses standard JSON library to achieve the desired effect. When you encounter this code, you immediately see that we're dealing with JSON serialization. OTOH, when you see `s.replace('"', '\\"')`, you have to guess what's going on.

Comment: Sometimes with imbedded python you might not have access to all the imports.

Comment: -1 in favour of `json.dumps(string)` as it's simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @tamakisquare Don't forget ***safer*** as well.

Comment: @tamakisquare Don't forget slower as well :) All depends

Answer (score 141):

You should be using the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. `json.dumps(string)`. It can also serialize other python data types.

```
import json

>>> s = 'my string with "double quotes" blablabla'

>>> json.dumps(s)
<<< '"my string with \\"double quotes\\" blablabla"'
```

Comment: Why does json.dumps() add in all of the extra quotes?  Why does it add an extra backslash i.e., \\", instead of just \"    ?

Comment: @user798719 it doesnt add extra \. thats the way it prints it in console.

Comment: TIL json.dumps can act on singleton strings as well as `dict` objects.

Comment: Would like to state that even though this is a nice method since it uses a standard library and has simple usage, using `json.dumps` is slow. Where speed is a crucial element, I would not recommend using this method.

Comment: as of 2023 I see no escape character here

Answer (score 64):

Note that you can escape a json array / dictionary by doing json.dumps twice and json.loads twice:

```
>>> a = {'x':1}
>>> b = json.dumps(json.dumps(a))
>>> b
'"{\\"x\\": 1}"'
>>> json.loads(json.loads(b))
{u'x': 1}
```

Comment: Working out of the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i know this question is old, but hopefully it will help someone.
i found a great plugin for those who are using PyCharm IDE:
[string-manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation)
that can easily escape double quotes (and many more...), this plugin is great for cases where you know what the string going to be.
for other cases, using `json.dumps(string)` will be the recommended solution

```
str_to_escape = 'my string with "double quotes" blablabla'

after_escape = 'my string with \"double quotes\" blablabla'
```