# scrapy throws error 500 after sending Post request

Tags: python-2.7, post, scrapy

I can successfully send Post request and receive all data through Postman.
Which returns this python code for export

```
import requests

url = "https://cl.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search"

payload = "{\"request\":{\"State\":\"PNavDS=N:0\",\"Keywords\":[],\"Page\":0,\"PageLayout\":0,\"Mode\":12,\"Term\":\"0\",\"ExchangeRate\":null}}"
headers = {
    'origin': "https://cl.ingrammicro.com",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'accept': "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "e4a3a94a-fa02-5ea3-2386-295a9fe21f3b"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

This post request returns neat **json** dict.

When I use the same in scrapy I got **500** error. 
Here is my Scrapy code.

```
url = "https://cl.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search"
            headers = {
                    'origin': "https://cl.ingrammicro.com",
                    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                    'content-type': "application/json",
                    'accept': "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
                    'cache-control': "no-cache",

                    }

            payload = {"request":{"State":"PNavDS=N:0","Keywords":[],"Page":0,"PageLayout":0,"Mode":12,"Term":"0","ExchangeRate":'null'}}

            return FormRequest(url, method = "POST", body=json.dumps(payload),headers = headers, callback=self.parse_data)
```

Scrapy error.

```
2017-07-31 16:59:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST https://cl.i
ngrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal
Server Error
2017-07-31 16:59:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST https://cl.ingrammicro.com/_lay
outs/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search> (referer: None)
```

I also tried to pass this as a string( as Postman code suggests) but the error is the same)

```
url = "https://cl.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search"
            headers = {
                    'origin': "https://cl.ingrammicro.com",
                    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                    'content-type': "application/json",
                    'accept': "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
                    'cache-control': "no-cache",

                    }
            payload = "{\"request\":{\"State\":\"PNavDS=N:0\",\"Keywords\":[],\"Page\":0,\"PageLayout\":0,\"Mode\":12,\"Term\":\"0\",\"ExchangeRate\":null}}"
            q = {"request":{"State":"PNavDS=N:0","Keywords":[],"Page":0,"PageLayout":0,"Mode":12,"Term":"0","ExchangeRate":"null"}}
            p={}
            p['request'] = str(q['request'])
            p['request']= p['request'].replace("'",'"')



            return FormRequest(url, method = "POST", body=urlencode(q) ,headers = headers, callback=self.parse_data)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you want scrapy for this, if you are sure you can do it using **requests**?

Comment: It has 600 pages, which is long enough, als this is 1 domain out of 3 for the same project with same item structure. So Scrapy is  my choice # 1.

Comment: Have you tried to pass `payload` to `formdata` argument of `FormRequest` instead of using `body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was replacing parts of the code with other parts.
But correct solution would be to use `json.dumps(payload)` which will give us exactly what we need to proceed and allows to manipulate dict as expected.
P.S. thanks to this answer - [by @zeekay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997098/7209826)