# How to convert a dict to an escaped JSON string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a `dict` of the form:

```
myDict = {'a': 'b'}
```

If I do `json.dumps(myDict)`, I get `'{"a": "b"}'`. So far so good.

What I'm trying to get is a string that looks like:

`{\"a\":\"b\"}` (in order to sign an API request).

I've tried doing `.replace('"', '\\"')`, which seemed to insert `\\`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes for JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997029/escape-double-quotes-for-json-in-python)

Comment: I tried it and got `{\"a\": \"b\"}`. Can you add a working example to see where we differ?

Comment: It seems weird to have to un-json the string to sign it. Shouldn't you be signing exactly what you send?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import json

myDict = {'a': 'b'}

print(json.dumps(myDict).replace('"', '\\"'))
```

Output:

```
{\"a\": \"b\"}
```

It works, it's just on the interpreter preview that it might seems to be double backslashed so you know that it is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague suggest this to me,
json can just dump you the string that you need

```py
print(json.dumps(json.dumps(myDict)))
```

```
>>> import json
>>> myDict = {'a': 'b'}
>>> print(json.dumps(json.dumps(myDict)))
"{\"a\": \"b\"}"
```