# How not to return \ in JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT patientFirstName, patientLastName FROM `patientmaster` WHERE nik = "1"')
patientProfile = cursor.fetchall()

patientProfileArray = []
patientName = None

for row in patientProfile:
    patientFirstName = row[0]
    patientLastName = row[1]

patientProfile = {'Patient': [{'patientFirstName': patientFirstName, 'patientLastName': patientLastName}]}

responseObject = {}
responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
responseObject['headers'] = {}
responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(patientProfile, default=str)
return responseObject
```

and it returns

```
{\"Patient\": [{\"patientFirstName\": \"vin\", \"patientLastName\": \"wan\"}]}
```

how do i remove the \ in json format

Comment: Those `\` do not exist in the actual JSON format, they're added by string representation. Where do you see that output?

Comment: i use an api and call it with postman

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997029/escape-double-quotes-for-json-in-python ?

Comment: not really sir i want to clean the json response from all those \

Comment: if it's a string then just do ```s.replace('\\', '')``` where s is the string. The backslashes are just escaping the double quotes. (The first backslash escapes the second, letting Python know it's a literal '\' , not escaping the following "

Comment: can i create the json response without the \ sir?

because I'm creating a json currently and I want it to look like a normal json format

Comment: I don't know. Read up on escapes in json.dumps() ?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are doing and what you see. Escaping with backslashes typically happens when you display a quoted string that contains quote characters. That does not mean that the backslashes are part of the string, only that this specific way of displaying them adds them for clarity. That's also the reason why your description is too vague to tell. All we know is that they are somewhere where you don't expect them, but that's not enougt to tell whether your expectations are wrong or the API response is wrong. Please provide a [mcve], read [ask] and take the [tour]!